# SSIS Error converting date from DT_STR to database timestamp [DT_DBTIMESTAMP]

Tags: ssis

I have a TAB Delimited file which I am downloading to a database table.  The table has columns with datatypes nvarchar(50) but a date column with datatype of datetime.  The TAB Delimited file has all datatypes DT_STR.  I converted all fields with datatype DT_STR to DT_WSTR but I need to convert the date from ST_STR to database timestamp [DT_DBTIMESTAMP].  However, I keep getting the following error:

```
[Data Conversion [2]] Error: Data conversion failed while converting column "Reason Code Date" (150) to column "Copy of Reason Code Date" (82).  
The conversion returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".

[Data Conversion [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  
The "Data Conversion.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[Copy of Reason Code Date]" failed because error code 0xC020907F occurred, and the 
error row disposition on "Data Conversion.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[Copy of Reason Code Date]" specifies failure on error. 
An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Data Conversion" (2) failed with error code 
0xC0209029 while processing input "Data Conversion Input" (3). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. 
The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  
There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

I need the date column in the table to look like this after the conversion:

```
ReasonDate
2018-04-19 00:00:00.000
2019-05-10 00:00:00.000
2018-12-09 00:00:00.000
2018-03-09 00:00:00.000
2018-09-21 00:00:00.000
2018-02-06 00:00:00.000
```

How can I achieve this without getting a conversion error?

Comment: Can you show us what the value you're inputting looks like? Without that we can't provide you suggestions. Changing the datatype for an input of "01-01-2018" is a lot different than an input of "January 1st, 2018". Without examples, for all we know, it could be either format of input

Comment: Adding the specific details about your whole Table definition would be helpful.

Comment: What is the date format in the flat file?

Comment: Hi PausePause, J.Murry, and Yahfoufi.  Thank you for your comments and suggestions.  I found out that the data was chopped off at the end of the list, which made the date column blank, and why I got the error.  I was able to resolve it and get the run completed successfully.  Thanks a million for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was determined that the data in the file was chopped off at the end of the list, which made the date column blank and why the error was encountered.  The problem was resolved by recreating the list with all the date fields having dates (MM/DD/YYYY format).  The dates was converted in SSIS from ST_STR to database timestamp [DT_DBTIMESTAMP], and when the job was run again the date conversion was done correctly (to format '2018-04-19 00:00:00.000'), and the job completed successfully.